# How to fix fatal error: sys/capability.h: No such file or directory

Tags: package-management, dependencies

When trying to build a [Openvpn3 from source](https://github.com/OpenVPN/openvpn3#building-the-openvpn-3-client-on-linux) and ran into this error. What package or library is needed to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[This page](https://man7.org/tlpi/code/faq.html) contains helpful information when looking for missing dependency errors. Here if we search for `sys/capability.h` we find in the page:

*error: sys/capability.h: No such file or directory*

If you encounter the error `sys/capability.h: No such file or directory`, it is because a required package is not installed on your system.

On Debian or Ubuntu, something like the following should work:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap-dev
```

Answer (score 2):

Generically, to find what package contains a missing file, you can use `apt-file` (not installed by default):

```
$ apt-file search sys/capability.h

gcc-i686-linux-android: /usr/x86_64-linux-gnu/i686-linux-android/include/sys/capability.h
libcap-dev: /usr/include/sys/capability.h
libklibc-dev: /usr/lib/klibc/include/sys/capability.h
```

The example above lists three packages which provide a file named `sys/capability.h`: `gcc-i686-linux-android`, `libcap-dev`, and `libklibc-dev`; One of these three is possibly the missing one.

Specifically for `openvpn3`, when building from source, the error message you encountered lists what file references `sys/capability.h` - you can `git blame <refering file>` to find what commit introduced the dependency on `sys/capability.h`, and examine that commit for other clues on what dependency was added. If the new dependency is a library which is not packaged for Ubuntu, `git blame` will get you closer to understanding what's missing.

I believe in your case, you're missing `libcap-dev` as @lacostenycoder pointed out.

I'm providing this improved answer in the hope that it lets future searchers understand where to find their answers more directly and quickly.